# Memory Leak with Collection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Please take a look at the following code.

```
     XmlManipulatorObject=[[xmlManipulator alloc] init];
     self.QuestionMutableArray=[[XmlManipulatorObject ReadXml] init];
     self.dictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

     self.dictionary=[QuestionMutableArray objectAtIndex:reloader];
```

in my dealloc method i need to release all the objects i am using above.What should be the way?

I tried with the following but having BAD_ACCESS :

```
   -(void)deallocAll
    {

       [self.dictionary release];
       [self.XmlManipulatorObject release];
       [self.QuestionMutableArray release];

   }
```

and the properties are as below :

```
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *QuestionMutableArray;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)xmlManipulator *XmlManipulatorObject;
```

Comment: Are you declaring your properties as (retain) ?

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *QuestionMutableArray;
@property(nonatomic,retain)xmlManipulator *XmlManipulatorObject;

Answer (score 3):

Ok you have a number of things wrong/ bad ideas happening here:

1. Variable and method names should start with a lowercase letter. This helps with readability and avoids confusion with class names. So XmlManipulatorObject should be xmlManipulatorObject, ReadXml should be readXml, etc.
2. When you create an instance of a class, you either should autorelease it or manually release it. For example:

   ```
   self.dictionary=[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
   ```

   or

   ```
   NSMutableDictionary *myDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
   self.dictionary=myDic;
   [myDic release];
   ```
3. From the above it also appears that you don't know about the way that properties handle retains and releases. Do some reading about properties.

Comment: if i use autorelease..will i need to release it again?and what about the xmlManipulatorObj and QuestionMutable array?I am on learning phase.I will be careful about the naming convention later.Please give me the proper instruction on it.

Comment: Can you tell me what about the the other two object.Do i need to release them too?

Comment: there are two things you need to understand and read about in the Apple documentation. Firstly the retain rules. One of which is that if you [... alloc] init...] something, you need to either release or autorelease it. Secondly, properties specified as @property (retain, ...) ... will automatically retain and release anything they store. I highly recommend you read through the documentation about memory management and properties to understand this because memory issues are the one thing that will drive you crazy and wreak your software if you don't understand them.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is far better to release your objects immediately after your done using them rather than at the dealloc method.

Also you should probably use the default dealloc method.

Also since you never called the dealloc super method you wont be releasing any memory.

```
-(void)deallocAll
{
   [self dealloc];

   [self.dictionary release];
   [self.XmlManipulatorObject release];
   [self.QuestionMutableArray release];
```

}

I would even go as far to change this from deallocAll to just dealloc.

Comment: It usually doesn't matter, but I always [super dealloc]; after releasing all of the current classes properties and variables. The reason is that I prefer to free up memory locally before I ask super classes to free their memory. I'm not aware of any case in my code where this has actually mattered, but I'm sure that it's possible to create a situation where freeing the super class memory before the current class will cause an error. Probably what we would call a "code smell" :-)

Answer (score 1):

drekka is right. You should note the below point too,

If you are using synthesized properties, set your variable to nil instead of releasing it.

```
self.yourObject = nil;
```

This will send the setter method 'nil' as a parameter, and your object will be released by the setter method.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I've had to chase down many memory bugs caused by properties not being released correctly, not being released at all, or in some cases being released twice. Unfortunately I work with some developers who are not as diligent as I on these things :-(

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what is the purpose of deallocAll. Well the best way i learned so far for that case:

```
NSObject *ob = [[NSObject alloc] init];
self.myObject = ob;
[ob release];
```

And in dealloc

```
-(void)deallocAll{
[super dealloc];
[myObject release];
```

}

Comment: problem is dealloc method is not responding so i am using deallocAll and using it in my viewDidDisappear.

Comment: sounds interesting.are you sure? check that by NSLog[ing]